# Error: ord < 26L is not TRUE

Tags: r, lme4

I am running a mixed effect model:

```
a1fit1.1=glmer(Outcome_AprWatch_Exclude ~ Herd_size_2 +  w4a + w4b + as.factor(AgeSex_4_Coded_Clean) + (1 | EncounterID), data=attack, family=binomial(link="logit"), verbose=TRUE, nAGQ=30)
```

The outcome is binary (0/1), predictor variables are continuous except for AgeSex which is a factor.  I have 303 observations nested within 173 Encounters (which is my random variable).  I have been working with this code successfully for over a year and a half, have run various similar models, and have had success with manipulating the number of integration points (nAGQ=1-30 or so).

For some reason, I have started to receive error messages when I run the code now, but only when I have nAGQ>1 (which I need as I would like/need to use adaptive gaussian hermite approximation and not the laplace approximation).

Here is the error I get now when I run my model with 30 intpoints

```
Error: ord < 26L is not TRUE
```

Here is the warning I now get with lower intpoint values (i.e., 2-7)

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00114606 (tol = 0.001)
```

Again, I get no error when I run it with nAGQ=1

As I said, this is the same model I have run many times with no previous errors.  In addition, I have checked this model in STATA (same model with 30 intpoints) and came across no errors and receive the same output that I had when I originally ran the model in R with no errors (which was only last week or so!).

I am unsure why lme4 is now giving me errors for code that I have been running successfully for a long time.  Was lme4 updated recently and are there bugs associated with the update?  Any help anyone can give would be wonderful.

FYI - I tried uninstalling and re-installing R, RStudio and lme4 with no change in error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.0 version of `lme4`came out last year and made significant changes to the code. Since you had began using `lme4` prior to that, it is conceivable your R may not have updated the package until today. At least that's what happened to me last month.

An lme4.0 package was actually developed to compare results from the old and new `lme4`. Here is a link (http://hlplab.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/old-and-new-lme4/). Note that the author has recently posted an update at the top of the page.

(Sorry I should've just commented but my permission does not allow it)

Comment: Good answer. See also: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/136 ; https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/README.md .  Version 1.1-7 (which will probably resolve your convergence warnings) should, hopefully, be up on CRAN in the next few days.